# Complexity of multiple variables

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, analysis

I was looking at some True/False statements for some Big-O notations with multiple variables and came up with this one below

[image]

`n^k ∈ O(k^n) - false`

I could not get my head around this statement and need some clarifications.

The explanation goes like

*if n is chosen to be a fixed value, and k → ∞, then the left-hand side of the equation becomes exponential whereas the right-hand side is polynomial. Hence, n^k is not bounded by k^n*

The conclusion becomes clear when `n` is chosen to be constant and `k → ∞` but why cannot we do the other way around, i.e. choose `k` as the constant and `n → ∞`? What is the rational behind choosing `n` as the constant here?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, based on the definition, you must validate both cases. In this proof, as one of them is failed, so we can say that `n^k` is not in `O(k^n)` for any `k` and `n`. Although the other side is correct if you take `k` as a constant (`>1`) and `n` goes to infinity.

Comment: okay, so we _do not have to_ validate both of the cases then?

Comment: @fnisi for the correctness you need both. But for disproving, one side is enough.